# Entity Framework table not updating database

Tags: entity-framework

My application does something strange, if I execute the following code outside the debugger it does not work, but if I run it with the debugger it works fine: keeping in mind that I step through the code, and not continue the next instant.

As I can gather from the debugger, there is nothing wrong with the code, but maybe there is, I at least cannot find it.

```
public void Reject(string id)
{
    using (context)
    {
        int intId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        Hours hr = (from h in context.Hours
                    where h.Id == intId
                    select h).FirstOrDefault();
        hr.Status = 30;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDBContext class**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tasks> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Hours> Hours { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OffDays> OffDays { get; set; }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.Department)
            .WithMany(d => d.Users)
            .Map(c => c.MapKey("DepartmentId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Supervisors)
            .WithMany();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasMany(d => d.Supervisors)
            .WithOptional()
            .Map(c => c.MapKey("SupervisorId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Hours>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.UserId)
            .WithMany(h => h.Hours)
            .Map((c => c.MapKey("Hours")));
    }
}
```

Do you guys have an idea what I can try?

Comment: Do you get an exception? Is `context` an instance field? Do you set it via the constructor? Do you call `Reject` or other methods multiple times for the same instance of the containing class?

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the *correct* database. Are you using a file-based database, ie use `AttachDBFileName` in the connection string?

Comment: I am using a file based database, the context is set in my baseController (it is MVC), and used everywhere, it connects to the right DB and I do not get an exception. CustomController>BaseController>Controller, that is the extention on my controllers

Comment: No, you aren't. The "correct" database is the file copied inside your `bin/debug` folder which always gets overwrittend when you hit F5. *Why* are you using a file-based database anyway? They don't scale, they are deprecated and they *will* be removed in a future versions. Check [Aaron Bertrand's](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) article on why you shouldn't use them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-something.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-aspnet-something;` That is how I declaired it, I assume that is the correct connectionstring.

Comment: try to add this code before "context.SaveChanges()" : 
            db.Entry(tablename).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

Comment: @AlirezaSoleimaniAsl this will have absolutely no effect. `SaveChanges` isn't broken. The *file* gets overwritten every time the web project is debugged

Comment: @AlirezaSoleimaniAsl should tablename not be the record that I modified?

Comment: @FalingDutchman The connection string is correct. The full path though is *relative* to the *execution* directory. During debugging, that is `bin\Debug`. All files in there get cleared and overwritten every time you rebuild your application

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is not the problem either, it is not between debugging sessions this happens, but during one session. With or without debugging this does not update the value correct, only if I step through my code slowly...

Comment: Then I suggest you post what *actually* happens, including the full code. At the very least include the code that generated the context and any code that may be opening a transaction. Why aren't you creating the context in your method? Where do you create it? Is `hr` a struct or a class? What happens if a record is *not* found? Shouldn't your code throw a NullReferenceException?

Comment: kanavos saying right, try create your context like this"private DBEntities context = new DBEntities();" . for updating a record you should be sure about being record in table with try exception. i suggest you to learn Entity  deeply: [Entity learning 1](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/) , [Entity learning 2 ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/19/absolue-beginners-guide-to-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Have you disabled change tracking perhaps?

Comment: This still bothers me `using (context)`.  Ideally it would be `using (var context = new MyContextClass()`.

Comment: Why is one context for the whole application a less ideal situation? I will try with a new context.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I have done that, it works. But what is different? If I could post the source I would, but that is not an option for me.

Comment: `DbContext` does a *ton* of internal caching.  If you ever fetched that same object in the past and it got disconnected then, by reusing the context you might get the disconnected cached version.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Ah okay, so where possible I should use a fresh copy. I have hunted down the porblem. Believe it or not, I removed the using statement and again the code worked like a charm without the `context.Attach(hr)` And it works fine with a fresh content, just not with the generic one. So I have learned my lesson today on what to not do, that is making an generic context.

Comment: @FalingDutchman  It's great that we managed to find the real root of your problem.  I've added an answer summarizing the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are reusing the same `DbContext` instance through the life of your application.  This goes against Microsoft's recommended best practices, and may introduce some of the odd behavior you are seeing.  `DbContext` manages a LOT of cached data inside each `DbContext` instance, and keeping it alive for the entire application can cause all sort of craziness as different cached entities are returned.  This caching is what I think is causing your problem.  Somewhere in your application this instance is getting disconnected from the context, and now that disconnected, cached instance is being returned the next time you ask for it.

The current Entity Framework best practices recommend that you create a new instance of the context for each logical "unit of work".

The easiest way to create a new context instance on demand is like this:

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    //Code here that uses the context
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first attach the entity that you have retrieved

```
public void Reject(string id)
{
    using (context)
    {
        int intId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        Hours hr = (from h in context.Hours
                where h.Id == intId
                select h).FirstOrDefault();
        context.Attach( hr);// here is difference
        hr.Status = 30;
        context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: The entity should already be attached by default unless he did something strange to the way the context is configured.

Comment: There is no reason to reattach an entity that was just loaded **unless** change tracking has been disabled explicitly

Comment: You are a magician, It works, first try, every try! @BradleyUffner my context works as supposed on every other page I made, so maybe it was a fluke that it worked on that pages, but at least I know the fix and will "fix" it on my other pages!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And I have not changed the tracking... But this still worked, so well, who cares :)

Comment: If you use context = new context(); entity  will be attached by default . May be your instance of context will change in your code .if my answer doesn't work comment to me .I will delete it

Comment: @mohsen It did work, so please let it stay, for the other overflowers :)

Comment: @FalingDutchman no it didn't work and *SHOULD NOT* be used by others. You still don't know what the problem is. You just glossed over it. *Why* was the entity detached? Why isn't this problem reproducible? How are you certain that some other method won't break if you don't know what to fix? Something is wrong with the context and this problem will appear again

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is correct, this just sweeps the real problem under the rug.  There is more going on here than it seems.  If you don't want more mysterious problems to pop up later, you need to get to the *real* root of the problem.

Comment: Try doing a global search in your entire solution for the string "ChangeTracking".

Comment: @BradleyUffner The strange thing is ChangeTracking is enabled, the string is not found and in the object explorer it says by the context.configuration that it is enabled... And as I am running the code inside a using block there is no chance that it for some odd reason will be disposed?

Comment: If you are using CodeFirst, can you update your question with the entire `DbContext` Class?  Also, do you have CodeFirst Migrations enabled?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes and Yes, and I updated the question :)